# Use fwrite to create an .md file

Tags: php, fwrite

I was wondering if there is any way to use `fwrite()` to create an .md file. I am creating a blog for a team that needs to upload content without me typing it out. The content is in markdown via an .md file for each post. I am trying to make a web page that will take content and create an .md file with it. Right now I just have a proof test running and am trying to save this to a .md file. However, when I try to change the extension to .md I keep getting errors. I'm kinda a PHP noob so your help is apricated.

**TLDR**

I'm wondering why this (`fwrite("newfile.md", "w") or die("Unable to create file!"`) would throw an error while using .txt won't.

**CODE**

```
<?php
$myfile = fwrite("newfile.md", "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Well what errors are you getting? And it'd probably be because you aren't opening the file.

Comment: @Darren I'm getting the die error message whenever the code is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue would be that you aren't opening/creating a file, you're just attempting to write to it. You need to use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) before you write to it:

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.md", "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Always the syntax that gets me. I'll mark this as correct in six minutes as soon as StackOverflow lets me.

Comment: @Joe789101112 Excellent, glad it works now! Remember you can also check out [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) as an alternative ;-)